# Is there a way to search how many dictionaries in a list have two specific values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

For example

```py
mylist = [{'animal': 'dog', 'price': 30, 'name': 'snowball'}, {'animal': 'cat', 'price': 40, 'name': 'max'}, {'animal': dog, 'price': 30, 'name': 'fido'}]
```

I know how to find how many dictionaries in the list have one parameter by using the following

```py
n_dogs = sum(x.get('animal') == 'dog' for x in mylist)
```

Which returns `2`, for the 2 dogs in the list.

Now how would I go about finding how many of the entries in the list are dogs with a price of `30`?

Would greatly appreciate any help :)

Comment: `sum(x.get('price') == 30 for x in mylist)`?

Comment: Thanks but that only shows how many animals are worth 30. I'm trying to find out how many of the dictionaries are DOGS and worth 30 as well

Comment: `sum(x['price'] == 30 and x['animal'] == 'dog' for x in mylist)`

Answer (score 0):

```
n_dogs_price_30 = sum(x.get('animal') == 'dog' and x.get('price') == 30 for x in mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a conditional statement in the generator expression:

```py
dogs = sum(x.get('price') == 30 for x in mylist if x.get('animal') == 'dog')
```

Using the conditional statement, it will not consider the entries which do not have a `key/value` pair of `"animal":"dog"`. If you would prefer a loop over the one-line generator above, that is also entirely possible:

```py
dogs = 0
for x in mylist:
    if x.get('animal') == 'dog' and x.get('price') == 30:
        dogs += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

`sum([x['animal'] == 'dog' and x['price'] == 30 for x in mylist])`

But I think that if you work with data the more elegant way is using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

mylist = [{'animal': 'dog', 'price': 30, 'name': 'snowball'}, {'animal': 'cat', 'price': 40, 'name': 'max'}, {'animal': dog, 'price': 30, 'name': 'fido'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
print(df[(df.animal == 'dog') & (df.price == 30)])
```